# Exit Button not working from Frame to Panel

Tags: java, swing

Warning: Beginner programming trying to Understand her homework!! Will ask dumb questions!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class StudentGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public StudentGUI()
    {
            super("StudentGUI Frame");



      //TopPanel
     TopPanel tp;
     tp=new TopPanel();

     Dimension d = new Dimension(800,600);
     tp.setPreferredSize(d);
     this.add (tp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
     tp.setVisible(true);
     this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     this.setSize(800,600);
        setBackground(Color.PINK);

        tp.setVisible(true);

        //TopPanel End


        //BottomPanel
        BottomPanel bp;
     bp=new BottomPanel();


     this.add (bp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
     tp.setVisible(true);
     this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     this.setSize(800,600);



        //BottomPanel End

        //MiddlePanel 

    MiddlePanel mp;
     mp=new MiddlePanel();


     this.add (mp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
     mp.setVisible(true);
     this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     this.setSize(800,600);

        //MiddlePanel End



        this.setVisible(true);


    }

    exitBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


  int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                              "Do you want to close the window?", 
                              "Choose", 
                              JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); 
    if (selectedOption == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        System.exit(1));



}
}
 }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new StudentGUI();
    }


}
```

Here is my main frame code.

And here is my Panel code that contains the Exit Button.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BottomPanel extends JPanel {

public String findbtn="";
public String insertBtn="";
public String updateBtn="";
public String deleteBtn="";
public String exitBtn="";

public BottomPanel() {
   JButton findbtn;
     findbtn=new JButton("Find");
        add(findbtn);

           JButton insertBtn;
     insertBtn=new JButton("Insert");
        add(insertBtn);

           JButton updateBtn;
     updateBtn=new JButton("Update");
        add(updateBtn);

           JButton deleteBtn;
     deleteBtn=new JButton("Delete");
        add(deleteBtn);

        JButton exitBtn;
     exitBtn=new JButton("Exit");
        add(exitBtn);
         exitBtn.addActionListener;


}
}
```

I've tried over and over to get the exit button to work, half of the time the program works but when I push the exit button nothing happens.
I am suppose to get it to the point where I click the Exit button, it ask if Im sure I want to exit, if I push no it doesn't if i push yes it does.

Comment: Does your code compile? In your StudentGUI class, you appear to be trying to add an ActionListener to a variable, exitBtn, that doesn't exist in that class. Why not add the ActionListener to the exitBtn inside of the BottomPanel class? Also, get rid of the confusing String variables.

Comment: Everytime I try that (I was told to do that before, I get a error

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It shouldn't compile. I found mismatched braces and parentheses when trying to auto-indent in emacs.

Comment: Is their anyone on here that can help me truly? You may know but I don't. I need the help, yet the comments go towards someone else explaining what is wrong, not helping me at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explained all my changes in the comments, this should work as long as your TopPanel and MiddlePanel classes have no problems. I just commented out those lines when testing it.

Change the first class to

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

// removed implements ActionListener
public class StudentGUI extends JFrame {
    public StudentGUI() {
        super("StudentGUI Frame");

        //TopPanel
        TopPanel tp;
        tp=new TopPanel();
        Dimension d = new Dimension(800,600);
        tp.setPreferredSize(d);
        this.add (tp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        tp.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(800,600);
        setBackground(Color.PINK);
        tp.setVisible(true);
        //TopPanel End

        //BottomPanel
        BottomPanel bp;
        bp=new BottomPanel();
        this.add (bp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        tp.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(800,600);
        //BottomPanel End

        //MiddlePanel 
        MiddlePanel mp;
        mp=new MiddlePanel();
        this.add (mp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mp.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(800,600);
        //MiddlePanel End

        this.setVisible(true);

        /* moved action listener within method, 
         * used bp.exitBtn instead of exitBtn
         */
        bp.exitBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    int selectedOption =
                        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                                                      "Do you want to close the window?", 
                                                      "Choose", 
                                                      JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); 
                    if (selectedOption == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }); // fixed braces, the closing paren should go here

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new StudentGUI();
    }
}
```

Your second class should be

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BottomPanel extends JPanel {
    /* instead of strings, added references to JButtons
     * so that they can be accessed from other classes
     */
    public JButton findbtn;
    public JButton insertBtn;
    public JButton updateBtn;
    public JButton deleteBtn;
    public JButton exitBtn;

    public BottomPanel() {
        findbtn=new JButton("Find");
        add(findbtn);

        insertBtn=new JButton("Insert");
        add(insertBtn);

        updateBtn=new JButton("Update");
        add(updateBtn);

        deleteBtn=new JButton("Delete");
        add(deleteBtn);

        exitBtn=new JButton("Exit");
        add(exitBtn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so it was like everyone was telling me, but my teacher said it shouldn't have code in the panels.. This is the most confusing bit of information my teacher has given me...

Comment: Now I get a illegal start of type for putting it in the Bottompanel, im back to phase 1.

Comment: OK, I fixed it. The "illegal start of type" was because you put the code outside of a method. There may be some problems with the other panels, but this should fix the exit button issue.

Answer (score 1):

I cleared up all the panels, leaving only the bottom panel for the purpose of demonstration.
In the BottomPanel, I fixed all the public strings into public JButton.
As Pat pointed out, that exitbtn should belong to something, and I made it belong to BottomPanel. You do not really need to implement interface ActionListener in JFrame. Here's the code for StudentGUI

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class StudentGUI extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public StudentGUI()
    {
        super("StudentGUI Frame");

        Dimension d = new Dimension(800,600);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(800,600);
        setBackground(Color.PINK);
        this.setVisible(true);


        //BottomPanel
        BottomPanel bp;
        bp=new BottomPanel();
        this.add (bp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        bp.exitBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to close the window?",    "Choose",   JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); 
                if (selectedOption == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) 
                    System.exit(1);
                return;
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new StudentGUI();
    }

}
```

And here is the code for BottomPanel:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BottomPanel extends JPanel {

    public JButton findbtn;
    public JButton insertBtn;
    public JButton updateBtn;
    public JButton deleteBtn;
    public JButton exitBtn;

    public BottomPanel() {
        findbtn=new JButton("Find");
        add(findbtn);
        insertBtn=new JButton("Insert");
        add(insertBtn);
        updateBtn=new JButton("Update");
        add(updateBtn);
        deleteBtn=new JButton("Delete");
        add(deleteBtn);
        exitBtn=new JButton("Exit");
        add(exitBtn);



    }
}
```

This is DEFINITELY not the best practice, but at least it works.

Comment: If it is not the best, why did my teacher ask for it this way? Does this hurt me in any way in the future or no?

Comment: Not really, it's not the best practice since all the buttons are made public. Normally, people want to make field variables private and use functions to get those variables out rather than accessing them straight away. But regarding functionality, there isn't really anything wrong.

Comment: Oh yes I understand you want your stuff private for security reasons! Thank you so much! You've really helped me.

Comment: Then you could tick my answer as the correct answer? :) :) Thanks heaps

Comment: I have no idea how to do that LOL.

Answer (score -1):

I was writing my answer but I was beaten to it. I would recommend using eclipse as you IDE. Your mistakes weren't programming mistakes. They were basic barrects. (All of us have been there :-D )

download eclipse here -->  https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-standard-432/keplersr2

Stuff underlined in red is error. If it's underlined in yellow in generally means it not being use. This will hopefully cut down your time looking for missing berracts.

Enjoy and keep learning :)

Comment: Yeah, a good editor is a must-have for programming. IMHO, an IDE like Eclipse is better for larger projects by experienced developers, but might not be the best choice for an intro comp sci class. I'd recommend using an editor like emacs and compiling with shell commands, which gives a better understanding of the compilation process (classpaths, etc.) .

Comment: There are some Lectures that in college believe that too. However as a student I disagree. You are told to use javac fileName.java to compile. At the end of the day your still only entering what you been told to enter. I understand that people are meant to go and research how it works but a lot of people don't.

Comment: (pressed enter by mistake) my last point. At the end of the day if you can't program, an IDE won't help, neither will a text editor. I don't think people should waste their time looking for brackets, etc. An IDE won't tell you why your array is null. The real learning is trying to find out why it wont work and when in your head it "should work". Hopefully I got my point across. Regards, J :)